# When to use value and reference types for immutable types? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, immutability

With mutable types, the difference in behaviour between value and reference types is clear:

```
// Mutable value type
PointMutStruct pms1 = new PointMutStruct(1, 2);
PointMutStruct pms2 = pms1;
// pms1 == (1, 2); pms2 == (1, 2);
pms2.X = 3;
MutateState(pms1); // Changes the X property to 4.
// pms1 == (1, 2); pms2 == (3, 2);

// Mutable reference type
PointMutClass pmc1 = new PointMutClass(1, 2);
PointMutClass pmc2 = pmc1;
// pmc1 == (1, 2); pmc2 == (1, 2);
pmc2.X = 3;
MutateState(pmc1); // Changes the X property to 4.
// pmc1 == (4, 2); pmc2 == (4, 2);
```

With immutable types however, this difference is less clear cut:

```
// Immutable value type
PointImmStruct pis1 = new PointImmStruct(1, 2);
PointImmStruct pis2 = pis1;
// pis1 == (1, 2); pis2 == (1, 2);
pis2 = new PointImmStruct(3, pis2.Y);
// Can't mutate pis1
// pis1 == (1, 2); pis2 == (3, 2);

// Immutable reference type
PointImmClass pic1 = new PointImmClass(1, 2);
PointImmClass pic2 = pic1;
// pic1 == (1, 2); pic2 == (1, 2);
pic2 = new PointImmClass(3, pic2.Y);
// Can't mutate pic1 either
// pic1 == (1, 2); pic2 == (3, 2);
```

Immutable reference types often use value semantics too (e.g. the canonical example `System.String`):

```
string s1 = GenerateTestString(); // Generate identical non-interned strings
string s2 = GenerateTestString(); // by dynamically creating them
// object.ReferenceEquals(strA, strB)) == false;
// strA.Equals(strB) == true
// strA == strB
```

Eric Lippert has discussed before on his blog (e.g. [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx)) that the fact that value types are often (when doesn't really matter for this discussion) allocated on the stack is an implementation detail and that it shouldn't generally dictate whether you make an object a value or reference type.

Given this blurred distinction in behaviour for immutable types, what criteria does this leave for us to decide whether to make an immutable type a reference type or a value type?

Also, with the immutable emphasis on values vs variables, should immutable types always implement value semantics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say that Eric's blog post you link gives you exactly the answer:

> I regret that the documentation does
>   not focus on what is most relevant; by
>   focusing on a largely irrelevant
>   implementation detail, we enlarge the
>   importance of that implementation
>   detail and obscure the importance of
>   what makes a value type semantically
>   useful. I dearly wish that all those
>   articles explaining what “the stack”
>   is would instead spend time explaining
>   what exactly “copied by value” means
>   and how misunderstanding or misusing
>   “copy by value” can cause bugs.

If your objects should have a "copy-by-value" semantic, then make them value types. If they should have a "copy-by-reference" semantic, make them reference types.

He also says this, which I agree with:

> I’d always make the choice of value
>   type vs reference type based on
>   whether the type is semantically
>   representing a value or semantically a
>   reference to something.

Comment: Value types are always stored within in the variable or field that represents them, wherever that variable or field happens to be stored.  Reference-type objects are never stored actually within the variable or field that represents them; they are always stored elsewhere on the heap.  If I have an object Foo1 of some class which contains a non-null field Bar1 of some reference type, then Foo1 and Bar1 are separate heap objects.  If I have an object Foo2 of some class which contains a Bar2 of a value type, then Bar2 will be stored within heap object Foo2.

Comment: @supercat This question revolves around a blog post arguing that using an _implementation detail_ of the runtime should not be the deciding factor of whether to use value types, but rather, the "copy-by-value" semantics of a value type over the "copy-by-reference" semantics of a reference type. I'm not really sure what your comment is adding other than a reinforcement about the very _implementation details_ that the post is suggesting programmers avoid.

Comment: If a type is immutable, copying a reference and copying a value will be semantically identical.  Unless the immutable type needs to have an inheritance relation with some other class (which is, to be sure, a useful pattern), the primary differences between an immutable value type and an immutable class type will relate to performance.  The primary question should be whether it's better to create a separate heap object for every different instance of the type, but possibly share instances known to be identical, or avoid creating heap objects to hold the instances.

Comment: I personally happen to believe that the disdain for mutable value types is largely an unfortunate consequence of some limitations and quirks in .net's handling of them, and that in many cases the way to achieve the best semantics and performance is to pass mutable value types by reference.

Comment: @supercat I don't think I really understand how your points relate. The whole reason that value types can even be created on the stack is because of their copy-by-value semantics. (It is guaranteed that a value object will never leak up the stack.) That said, and I think this is covered in the article, it is not even guaranteed that a value object is allocated on the stack. The only thing that should be exposed to the programmer is whether the types created are copy-by-value or copy-by-reference. Everything else should just be considered programmer-opaque runtime optimization by the VM.

Comment: The Lippert article doesn't even mention mutability.

Answer (score 2):

There is an important category of immutable types (that Eric Lippert has also written about at some length) that must be implemented as reverence types: recursive types such as list nodes, tree nodes, and the like. Value types can't have cyclical definitions, as, for example, a linked list node does:

```
class IntNode
{
    private readonly int value;
    private readonly IntNode next;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.NET sort of hints at an answer to this with the `String` class.  It’s immutable, but is a reference type.  Make your immutable type *act* like a value type as much as possible.  It doesn’t matter if it actually is a value type.

So the only criteria I can think of is: If copying it is going to be expensive (a `String` could involve a lot of copying!), make it a reference type.  If it’s quick to copy, go for a value type.  Also consider if you need to compare references – that’s probably the only tricky part with immutable reference types.